# Power Query: Calculate date/time instances within and over 1 day and show them as percentages (system utility time %)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, powerquery, excel-2016

I have some system data set where I wanna find comparison between two systems (Uptimum + scrubber), utility time (%) of how much of percentage they were operational during 24h but also if it exceeds 24h.

Data set is below data, but as you can notice - there are dates in **Column A (date)** gaps there, some days are missing and that will be like that from time to time. But there are also more system instances within one day (system operation can be changed many times per day), that is a reason there is a time in **Column B** (**time column**) so I can follow the exact timing of operation within a day.

[image]

**There is no official "end time" here, it is just ongoing process where operations (systems) are changing/shifting among many other parameters.**

What I did is, I extracted dates in **Column F** so to avoid duplicates and summed them up per system (**G2 and H2 Columns**), using this functions below and you can see screenshot below too:

```
=SUMIFS(Explog2021_04_28[T];Explog2021_04_28[D];$F2;Explog2021_04_28[System];"<>"&G$1)-SUMIFS(Explog2021_04_28[T];Explog2021_04_28[D];$F2;Explog2021_04_28[System];G$1)+(INDEX(Explog2021_04_28[System];MATCH($F2;Explog2021_04_28[D]))=G$1)-(INDEX(Explog2021_04_28[System];MATCH($F2;Explog2021_04_28[D];0))<>G$1)*$B2
```

With this function I summed **Columns A and B** using extracted values of date and system options.

[image]

First thing as you can notice I have minus values as percentage, it shouldnt be there, is that because I have so many gaps in dates? Is there a better way to fix this? As you can see on chart it looks bad..
This shouldnt also exceed 100% of overall usage if that is possible.

Every input would be great from you.

[image]

Comment: I am unclear what the datetimes represent.  Are they the start time of the operation in Column C?  And would the next datetime be a "switching time" to the subsequent operation?  Does that mean, for example,  that the operations was `Scrubber` from `23.02.2021 18:43:37` until `24.02.2020 18:31:32` at which time it switched to `Uptimum`?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld DateTime is start time, there is no "end time", it is just shifting between systems automatically until some other processes are done...but you got right it is exactly as you said...

Comment: So the fact that there is a "gap" merely means that the preceding operation continued for for more than a day.  Correct?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Hm yea correct, that is bugging me...because by other systems it is fine and this method of calculation is good, but suppose to be "gaps" from time to time and it is important to know that and to calculate it properly...

Comment: The compensation for system time spanning more than one day can certainly be done in Power Query, which is one of your tags.

Comment: I am pretty sure It can be done on one or another way, that is a reason I wrote for a help.

Comment: Working on it. Just needed to clarify the problem in my head

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, I believe the following Power Query should accomplish what you are looking for.

Please read the code comments and step through the applied steps window to understand the algorithm.  Ask if you have questions, and complain if there are logic errors.

I assumed that the system was always in either `scrubber` or `Uptimum`

**M Code**

```
let

//Read in data. Change table name in next line to reflect actual table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="systemTable"]}[Content],

//Type the columns
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"D", type text}, {"T", type any}, {"System", type text}}),
    #"Changed Type with Locale" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"D", type date}}, "en-150"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type with Locale",{{"T", type time}}),

//Combine date and time => datetime
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "startTime", 
        each DateTime.From(Number.From([D]) + Number.From([T])), type datetime),

//create shifted column to be able to quickly refer to previous row
//this method much faster than using an Index column
    Base = #"Added Custom",
    ShiftedList = List.RemoveFirstN(Table.Column(Base, "startTime"),1) & {null},
    Custom1 = Table.ToColumns(Base) & {ShiftedList},
    Custom2 = Table.FromColumns(Custom1, Table.ColumnNames(Base) & {"endTime"}),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Custom2,{{"endTime", type datetime}}),

//Create a list of dates for each time span
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type2", "datesList", each 
        let 
            st = DateTime.Date([startTime]),
            et = DateTime.Date([endTime] ),
            dur = Duration.TotalDays(et-st)
        in 
            if et=null then {st} else List.Dates(st,dur+1,#duration(1,0,0,0))),

//Expand the list so we have sequential dates (fill in the gaps)
    #"Expanded datesList" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Added Custom1", "datesList"),

//Remove unneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded datesList",{"D", "T"}),

//change date list datatype to datetime for simpler calculation formula
    #"Changed Type3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns",{{"datesList", type datetime}}),

//calculate hours in System each day
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type3", "Hrs in Day", 
        each List.Min({Date.EndOfDay([datesList]),[endTime]}) - List.Max({[startTime],[datesList]}),Duration.Type),

//Remove unneeded columns
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"startTime", "endTime"}),

//change date list to dates for report
    #"Changed Type5" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns1",{{"datesList", type date}}),

//Group by Date and System to calculate percent time in system
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type5", {"datesList", "System"}, {
        {"Sum", each List.Sum([Hrs in Day])/#duration(0,24,0,0), Percentage.Type}}),

//Pivot on System to generate final report
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Grouped Rows", List.Distinct(#"Grouped Rows"[System]), "System", "Sum", List.Sum),

//Rename the datelist column
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{{"datesList", "D"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

**Data**
[image]

**Results**
[image]

[image]

Comment: I saw quickly from my phone, and this looks very promising...I will check it thoroughly and will let you know my opinion and result. Thanks anyways

Comment: So, this works promising, it gives me lot of space to tweak what I need if needed, but the way you did is really good.
This parts of your code I changed a bit:

#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"D", type text}  into "D", type datetime (probably because of my regional settings) 

Can you tell me what is "en-150" by date format? What is german code if you know? I looked for this code line but couldnt find anything...

Comment: If something pops up with this topic in next days I will write but I think this is enormous help and approach that you did here, it is applicable in most of my cases.
Big thanks!

Comment: @Mirza `en-150` specifies that the date data is in `English(European)` format or `DMY`. Since my regional settings are `MDY` this was necessary to properly translate the date.  Setting the type to `Text` initially was possibly unneccessary, but it would prevent unwanted ***corrections*** from being made.  If your regional settings are the same as the date data format, this might not be necessary (unless the code might be running on a computer with other settings). Accessed in the UI by a dropdown on clicking the column and selecting Change Type according to Locale.

Comment: [Full list of Locale settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-lcid/a9eac961-e77d-41a6-90a5-ce1a8b0cdb9c?redirectedfrom=MSDN)  `English-Germany: en-DE`, `German-Germany: de-DE`